# Navigation flyout div won't show in IE

Tags: css, flash, uinavigationbar, z-index, css-position

My css-driven navbar works fine in Firefox, but not in IE. I think it has something to do with the Flash movie it flys out on. My page is [here](http://masonpud1.org/index.html). The very first menu item is "Customer Service" and it should have a flyout item of "Claim Forms." I have tried using the wmode=transparent in my Flash embed and messed with z-index in my navbar elements, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: you forgot the = in wmode="transparent"...

Comment: wow, thanks. Still doesn't show at all in IE though. I've gone through this in the past and was able to make it work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Your page works fine in my IE 8, but it complains about the missing mmLoadMenus() function.  Perhaps it has something to do with that?  What version of IE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to give z-index value to container of the menu (with position relative). And also flash must have wmode transparent.